# Getting a SIGSEV (Segmentation) Error in the following C++ code

Tags: c++, lambda, g++, c++17

```
struct CarDetected {
    double distance_m;
    double velocity_mps;
};

template<typename T>
struct AutoBrake {
    AutoBrake(const T &publish) :
            publish { publish } {
    }
    void observe(const CarDetected &cd) {

        publish();
    }

private:
    const T &publish;
};

void alert_when_imminent() {
    int brake_commands_published { };
    AutoBrake auto_brake { [&brake_commands_published]() {
        brake_commands_published++;
    } };
    auto_brake.observe(CarDetected { 100L, 0L });
}

int main() {
    alert_when_imminent();
}
```

I am passing a lambda function to the AutoBrake object **auto_brake** .In the method **observe** which has parameter of the type **(const CarDetected &cd)** when I call the lambda function, to execute the command **brake_commands_published++;** I am getting a SIGSEV error.

But when the method parameters of **observe** are passed by value as **void oberve(CarDetected)** then the code is executing as expected.

I am not understanding why the **const** which is associated with the **CarDetected** object is causing an error when increasing the value of **brake_commands_published** using a lambda.

What is the solution if I don't want to change the parameters of the method observe i.e I want observe to retain the parameters **void oberve(CarDetected)**.

P.S. Compiler the program with the -std=c++17 flag.

Comment: The lambda passed to the constructor of `AutoBrake` is a temporary and is destroyed at the end of the full expression; leaving `publish` a dangling reference. Note that life time extension (binding a temporary to a reference) is not transitive. Remove the reverence (`&`) from the constructor parameter and member variable.

Comment: No the publish is not dangling . It is referring to the lambda as expected . Also in the observe routine we are still in the scope of the alert_when_imminent function thus object and lambda are both alive .I checked this using the debugger.

Comment: `AutoBrake auto_brake { [&brake_commands_published]() { brake_commands_published++; } };`  The lamba created here is a temporary object - how does it continue existing past the end of the full expression (the `;`) ?